# How to pass success page controller data to view page tpl file in opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

Actually, i'm working on opencart 2.0.1.1, i'm getting order data from module file i want to pass the data to view file how to pass this data please help any one,this is showing issue like:Notice: Undefined index: order_id.
here my controller code:success.php

```
    $this->load->model('checkout/order'); 
    $data['orderDetails'] = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/common/success.tpl', $data));   
   //echo "<pre>";print_r($data['orderDetails']);die;
```

Here view code:success.tpl:

```
<div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
      <h1><?php echo 'Order Details'; ?></h1>
      <?php echo $orderDetails; ?>
    </div>
```